# Image is not loaded in MVC5 JQuery during initial Load requested via IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

1.When pointing the URL as "http:/servername/virtualdirectory" and for example i am setting image path as ../Content/Images/xx.png using jquery in js file then the images is not loaded

2.When pointing the URL as "http:/servername/virtualdirectory/controllername/action" and for example i am setting image path as ../Content/Images/xx.png using jQuery in js file then the Images is loaded.

Questions is why the image is not loaded during IIS request from routeconfig.cs ie 'http:/servername/virtualdirectory' in MVC5

Comment: You really have to improve on your English first, because this is, unfortunately, too hard to follow for me ...

Comment: Where is the Content folder located according to your website root?

Comment: Content folder is located at root and i am setting image url using jquery as for example ../Content/Images/xx.png

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<img src="~/Content/Images/xx.png">` in your `Razor` syntax. This will generate a correct path to your image.

Comment: I am assigning image path using jquery(for example ../Content/Images/xx.png) and also ~ will not works in JQuery